# How do i use try-catch statement with switch case but loop the swich case?

Tags: java

I am very new to Java and im trying to use try-catch statements. I would like to add a try catch case, but when i add it, the message just prints once and ends. I woudl like to reprint:

```
System.out.println("Press \"1\" to chat" + " & " + "\"2\" to play games" + " & \"3\" to edit the conversations");
        System.out.println("Typing other numbers will end the Chatbot");
```

but the program just ends. Is there a way to loop the try-catch statement?

```
    Scanner userinput = new Scanner(System.in);
    int startup;
    //popup for 1 to chat, 2 to play and 3 to edit
    while (true) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Press \"1\" to chat" + " & " + "\"2\" to play games" + " & \"3\" to edit the conversations");
            System.out.println("Typing other numbers will end the Chatbot");
            startup = userinput.nextInt();
            switch (startup) {

                case 1:
                    ConversationBot chat = new ConversationBot();
                    chat.ChattingBot();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    GameBot game = new GameBot();
                    game.GamingBot();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    EditBot edit = new EditBot();
                    edit.EditingBot();
                    break;
                default:
                    System.exit(0);
            }
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid User Input. Please enter a value from 0 to 4.");
            break;
        }
        String returningCode = returnChoiceOfChatbot(startup);
        System.out.println(returningCode);
    }
```

Thank you for the help.
BTW this is the returnChoiceOf Chatbot method

```
public static String returnChoiceOfChatbot(int input) {
    String returnChoice = null;
    switch (input) {
        case 1:
            returnChoice = ("You have chosen to chat with me!");
            break;
        case 2:
            returnChoice = ("you have chsen to play word games with me!");
            break;
        case 3:
            returnChoice = ("Please enter an input that you would give to the Chatbot.");
            break;
        default:
            System.exit(0);
    }
    return returnChoice;

}//end of returnChoice method
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace the line `break;` with `continue;` in your `catch` block. You want to ask the user for a new input if it wasn't a number. Otherwise that `break` breaks the whole `while` loop and prevents it from running again. This said, it should read:

```
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid User Input. Please enter a value from 0 to 4.");
        continue; // Jump back to the beginning of the while-loop
    }
```

Also check if you need to move these two lines:

```
String returningCode = returnChoiceOfChatbot(startup);
System.out.println(returningCode);
```

outside of your while loop. While it's not clear to me what they are for, it looks like you might want to run them only once after the while loop was left.

Comment: given it's a `while (true)` and the only way out of it is a `System.exit(0)`, I would imagine those lines are where they're supposed to be

Comment: I would have said they should run every time 'round the loop, since they relate to the choice each time

Answer (score 1):

The `break` statement (when used without a label to specify what to break out of) will exit the nearest `switch`, `while`, `for` or `do` .. `while` loop.

You generally *have* to use it with `switch` as you do to stop the execution falling through to the next case - e.g. if you didn't have the breaks and the user selected `1`, it would execute the code for all three cases, and then exit the program.

Inside your `catch` block however, the `break` exits the `while` loop. Since the intention is to tell the user their input is invalid and then ask for new input, this isn't what you want to do here. You *could* change the `break` to a `continue` which would abort the *current iteration* of the `while` loop and start the loop again, however generally speaking this sort of flow control will make your program harder to follow and therefore maintain.

I'm guessing you put the last `break` in to skip over the `returnChoiceOfChatbot(...)` code when the input is invalid. But this is exactly what exceptions are for - aborting the normal flow of code when something unexpected happens. So just move the "normal flow" code all inside the `try` block, and you won't need `break` (or `continue`) at all:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Press \"1\" to chat" + " & " + "\"2\" to play games" + " & \"3\" to edit the conversations");
        System.out.println("Typing other numbers will end the Chatbot");
        startup = userinput.nextInt();
        switch (startup) {
          // cases in here as before, omitted for brevity
        }
        String returningCode = returnChoiceOfChatbot(startup);
        System.out.println(returningCode);
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid User Input. Please enter a value from 0 to 4.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.println("Invalid User Input. Please enter a value from 0 to 4.");
    break;
}
```

Just remove the `break`. It doesn't have anything to do with the `catch` specifically, just with the `break` that you wrote in it.

Comment: looks like the two lines after the `catch` shouldn't run if the exception happens - so either a `continue` like Lars Blumberg suggested, or moving those lines inside the `try` would make sense, rather than just removing the `break`

Comment: @CupawnTae They should certainly be inside the `try` block. I will never understand why people put `try/catch` continuations outside the `try` block.

Comment: agreed, but in fact if you "just remove the `break`" it won't compile, because `startup` may not have been initialized when it's used. So you *must* either move the code (yes) or use a `continue` (as in Lars's answer)